# Map marker title does not show full text on Google map V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have multiple markers with its information on the map. By tapping on a particular marker it shows information.
Below is the code for adding multiple markers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));
    String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");
    String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title(name + ":" + vicinity);
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

My output is seen like this:

[image: output]

When I tap on a marker it is not displaying the full text. Instead of that it shows me some text and after some dots display.

Is there any method in Google Map V2 to show the full text? I already use the `title()` method of the "MarkerOptions" class.

Comment: If you used `Default Marker` then there is no way. But you can used `Custom Marker Window` for this.

Comment: Lawrence, nop there is no any method regarding this, its default Google map things, but you can do this after using Custom Marker.

Comment: @pratik can you please give me link of Custom Marker.

Comment: @Lawrence yup sure, why not

Comment: Instead of using `Marker.title(String)`, which ellipsizes the text if it overflows, use `Marker.snippet(String)`.

Comment: @Lawrence I have whole code if you needed dear?

Comment: @pratik ok no problem.

Comment: @pratik i think you should see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for helping.But I solved my issue.

Just create one class which extends InfoWindowAdapter.

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;
    private String name, vicinity;

    public MyInfoWindowAdapter(String name, String vicinity) {
        myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        this.name = name;
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.title));
        tvTitle.setText(name);
        TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentsView
                .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        tvSnippet.setText(vicinity);

        return myContentsView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And use setInfoWindowAdapter() method of GoogleMap.

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter(name,
                    vicinity));
```

Comment: @pratik yes working perfectly. Just need to add "markerOptions.title(name);markerOptions.snippet(vicinity);"

Comment: hey its fine then, I am just prepared your code to send u, but if u done thn its fine

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(origin); 
    options.title("Current Location");
    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mMap.addMarker(options);
```

Hope this will help you